# Silex clear cookie

Tags: cookies, silex

I'm using Silex and I'm trying to clear a cookie. The docs provided for Silex about cookie control is poor, so I have relied on Symfony2 - unfortunately I can't get it working!

```
$shop->match('/expire', function(Request $request) use ($app) {

    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->clearCookie('order');
    $response = $app['twig']->render('completed.html.twig');

    return $response;

});
```

In another attempt I tried re-setting the cookie with a negative expire time, but that didnt work either. No errors at all.

Anyone got a clue what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are creating a response object, setting the correct headers but then replacing it with a string of the content. Here is what you should do:

```
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->clearCookie('order');
$response->setContent($app['twig']->render('completed.html.twig'));

return $response;
```

Answer (score -1):

"remove" is enough for me: `$app['session']->remove('order');`